# Find the average value of $f(x)=x^2+5$ in $[0,3]$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the average value of $f\left(x\right)=x^2+5$ for $x \in [0,3]$. So far using

$$\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx$$

I got $\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x^3}{3}+5x\right)$ so do I just plug in the $0,3$ from here?

Comment: Yes, that is what you do: $\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{x^3}{3}+5x\right)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=3}$

Answer (score 1):

To be explicit,
$$\begin{align}
\text{average of }f(x)\text{ over }[0,3] &= \frac{1}{3-0} \int_0^3 (x^2+5) \,dx \\
&= \left. \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{x^3}{3} + 5x \right) \right|_0^3 \\
&= \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{3^3}{3} + 5\cdot 3 \right) - 0 \\
&= 8
\end{align}$$

I mainly typed up this answer because I can't comment yet. So what I wanted to say is that you should avoid using the language of "plug in". You should use the word "evaluate" in such cases.

And since you were stuck here, I recommend recalling what it means to have a definite integral where you evaluate the result at the endpoints. I.e., if $F'(x) = f(x)$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a)$.